# Flutter AutoComplete not showing all suggestions

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

im using intellij idea for flutter,
before when i want to use colors or any kind of style in flutter i used to only type any word and a suggestion would pop up with correct suggestions , check the image below plz,
i used to type - white - or any color and auto complete suggestion pop up with Colors.white or when i want to change font size i only type (si) and a suggestion window pop up with fontSize,

just recently since 2 days, its not working any more, when i type white, it wont show quick suggestions anymore

[white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brt3T.png)

strange thing is it's working on other places like when i type (cen) it shows correct suggestions (check image below plz) :

[center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMdcN.png)

i have the latest version of intellij idea

Comment: looks related to https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6176; actually code completion in Dart/Flutter comes from the Dart Analysis Server, a tool from the Dart SDK. So, in many cases IDE version doesn't matter but Dart SDK version does.

Comment: @lena thank you for the info, hopefully they will fix it soon coz it's been very helpful